# What should I do if people ask me to give my email?

Tags: discussion

Once or twice I came across a situation in which people asked me to give my email or personal contact info. What should I do in such situations? Should I ignore them or entertain them?

Comment: Ignore them? Say no thanks? Give it to them? Not sure what answer you expect to this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unless you really, really want to give them your e-mail/contact details - simply ignore them.

You are under no obligation to have any contact with any user outside of the site.

Please flag the comment(s) so we can remove them.

If they keep on harassing you on site through comments etc then flag one of these for moderator attention and we'll see what we can do. We can't promise it *will* stop but we can make it difficult for the perpetrator.

Comment: But shouldn't a request for email address be flagged for moderation? I believe that one of the main goals of this site to build a publicly available repository of common programming questions and answers, and so wouldn't allowing requests for off-site communication and potentially off-site question answering go against this goal?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - yeah, I should have added a point about getting the comments removed, but only because they're noise.

Comment: Many people add their email in their profile description, add link to their github, twitter, fb, or personal site. Also, there is the developer story where the email and phone number both are usually available, so I don't believe that SO doesn't or shouldn't allow off-site communication.

Comment: @mega6382 indeed, but that's different from asking for contact details from someone who *hasn't* shared them in their profile. We are neutral on whether you want to share your details or not, we are not neutral on people being potentially harassed.

Comment: Harassment is one (important) thing to consider. Besides that: such requests are easily made with the assumption that the other person can "simply say no". Except that this is a big assumption, this big world we're sharing has many corners where culturally there are barriers to saying no to a person, whether a stranger or not. IMO its against the "be nice" policy to make such off-topic personal requests, or should be.